# R - export worldclim variables at coordinates

Tags: r, environment-variables, extract

What I did:

Download some occurence data for the genus Cryptorama Fall from

```
library(dismo)

data <- gbif(genus='Cryptorama Fall, 1905 ', geo = TRUE)

data <- data.frame(x = data$lon, y = data$lat, specie = data$species)

data <- unique(data) # remove duplicates

data <-data[complete.cases(data),] # remove NA cells

#Get some data from Worldclime 

bioworldclim <- raster::getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10)

bioworldclim <- bioworldclim[[c(1,2)]] 

Bioclimenames(bioworldclim) <-c("bio1","bio2")
```

And now I want to extract the worldclim values for that locations of the genus and I do:

```
Cryptorama_bioclim <- extract(bioworldclim, data) and more "species"(if possible)
```

I loose the x y coordinates from the data file.
And I would like to have a similiar output:

```
x y "species" "bio1" "bio2"
```

Not sure if the `extract` functionis the correct function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
d <- cbind(data, Cryptorama_bioclim)
```

The thing to understand is that the data extracted has the same number of rows (or length) as the points used, and they are in the same order.